# Setting constraints to UITableView Footer Swft

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to place a footer with a UIButton, now I placed it only with frame and when I try it out across apple's iphones the button is not placed well due to the fact that I didn't set any auto-layout, the thing is Im trying to set auto-layout to the footer and it fails all the time also I'm not sure if its possible doing that, would love to get a handy help with that or even hints :).
Here's my code of the tableView:

```
import UIKit
import PanModal

protocol FilterTableViewDelegate {
    func didUpdateSelectedDate(_ date: Date)
}

class FilterTableViewController: UITableViewController, PanModalPresentable {
    
    var panScrollable: UIScrollView? {
        return tableView
    }
    
    
    var albumsPickerIndexPath: IndexPath? //  indexPath of the currently shown albums picker in tableview.
    var delegate: FilterTableViewDelegate?
    
    var datesCell = DatesCell()
    
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTableView()
        //        registerTableViewCells()
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        //        tableView.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
    
    
    
    // MARK: - View Configurations
    
    func setupTableView() {
        
        
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        
        
        tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        tableView.allowsSelection = true
        
        
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600
        
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        
    }
    
    
    
    func indexPathToInsertDatePicker(indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
        if let albumsPickerIndexPath = albumsPickerIndexPath, albumsPickerIndexPath.row < indexPath.row {
            return indexPath
        } else {
            return IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: indexPath.section)
        }
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // If datePicker is already present, we add one extra cell for that
        if albumsPickerIndexPath != nil {
            return 5 + 1
        } else {
            return 5
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            
            let byActivityCell = UINib(nibName: "byActivityCell",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byActivityCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byActivityCell")
            let activityCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byActivityCell", for: indexPath) as! byActivityCell
            activityCell.selectionStyle = .none
            
            return activityCell
            
        case 1:
            let byTypeCell = UINib(nibName: "ByType",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byTypeCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byTypeCell")
            let typeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byTypeCell", for: indexPath) as! ByType
            typeCell.selectionStyle = .none
            return typeCell
            
        case 2:
            let byHashtagsCell = UINib(nibName: "ByHashtags",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byHashtagsCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byHashtagsCell")
            let hashtagsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byHashtagsCell", for: indexPath) as! ByHashtags
            hashtagsCell.selectionStyle = .none
            
            return hashtagsCell
            
        case 3:
            let byDatesCell = UINib(nibName: "DatesCell",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byDatesCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byDatesCell")
            let datesCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byDatesCell", for: indexPath) as! DatesCell
            datesCell.selectionStyle = .none
            datesCell.datesTableViewCellDelegate = self
            
            return datesCell
            
            
        case 4:
            let byAlbumCell = UINib(nibName: "AlbumCell",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byAlbumCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byAlbumCell")
            let albumCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byAlbumCell", for: indexPath) as! AlbumCell
            albumCell.configureCell(choosenAlbum: "Any")
            albumCell.selectionStyle = .none
            
            return albumCell
            
            
            
        case 5:
            let albumPickerCell = UINib(nibName: "AlbumsPickerTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(albumPickerCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "albumPickerCell")
            let albumsPicker = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "albumPickerCell", for: indexPath) as! AlbumsPickerTableViewCell
            
            
            return albumsPicker
            
            
        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    // MARK: - footer Methods:
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return getfooterView()
    }
    
    func getfooterView() -> UIView
    {
        let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 400))
        let applyFiltersBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 380, height: 40))
        
        
        applyFiltersBtn.center = footerView.center
        
        applyFiltersBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        applyFiltersBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        applyFiltersBtn.setTitle("Apply Filters", for: .normal)
        applyFiltersBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1957295239, green: 0.6059523225, blue: 0.960457623, alpha: 1)
        
        
        //        doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hello(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        
        
        footerView.addSubview(applyFiltersBtn)
        
        
        return footerView
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    // MARK: TableViewDelegate Methods:
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        
        
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        
        // 1 - We Delete the UIPicker when the user "Deselect" thr row.
        if let datePickerIndexPath = albumsPickerIndexPath,   datePickerIndexPath.row - 1 == indexPath.row {
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [datePickerIndexPath], with: .fade)
            self.albumsPickerIndexPath = nil
        } else {
            // 2
            //            if let datePickerIndexPath = albumsPickerIndexPath {
            //                tableView.deleteRows(at: [datePickerIndexPath], with: .fade)
            //            }
            albumsPickerIndexPath = indexPathToInsertDatePicker(indexPath: indexPath)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [albumsPickerIndexPath!], with: .fade)
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }
        
        
        
        tableView.endUpdates()
        
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        if indexPath.row == 4  {
            return indexPath
        } else {
            return nil
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
}


extension FilterTableViewController: DatesTableViewCellDelegate {
    
    func didButtonFromPressed() {
        print("Button From is Pressed")
        let pickerController = CalendarPickerViewController(
            baseDate: Date(),
            selectedDateChanged: { [weak self] date in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                
                //          self.item.date = date
                //TODO: Pass the date to the DatesCell to update the UIButtons.
                self.delegate?.didUpdateSelectedDate(date)
                
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)], with: .fade)
            })
        
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    
    
    func didButtonToPressed() {
        //TODO: Present our custom calendar
        let calendarController = CalendarPickerViewController(
            baseDate: Date(),
            selectedDateChanged: { [weak self] date in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)], with: .fade)
            })
        
        
        
        self.present(calendarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: You're creating your `footerView` with a frame height of `400`? Is that the height you want for each section footer? Or, do you want a button height of `40` with a little space on top and bottom?

Comment: And... should this be a **Table** footer? Or a footer for each section?

Comment: @DonMag I set the height to be 400 cause of the UIButton but the thing is the footer is not auto-layout and when I try it out at for example at iphone pro (Im working on iphone11) then the button is down :\ it should be a table footer for one section- just to be a footer at the bottom with a uibutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a tip (based on this and other questions you've posted): Simplify what you're doing. When you post code referencing 5 different cell classes along with code for handling cell action delegates, inserting and deleting, etc... ***but*** your question is about Section Footer layout, it gets difficult to help.

So, here's an example of a simple table view controller, using a default cell class, and a custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` for the section footer:

```
class MySectionFooterView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    
    let applyFiltersBtn = UIButton()
    
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        configureContents()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configureContents()
    }
    
    func configureContents() {

        applyFiltersBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        applyFiltersBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        applyFiltersBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        applyFiltersBtn.setTitle("Apply Filters", for: .normal)
        applyFiltersBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1957295239, green: 0.6059523225, blue: 0.960457623, alpha: 1)

        contentView.addSubview(applyFiltersBtn)

        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // use layoutMarginsGuide for top and bottom
            applyFiltersBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            applyFiltersBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // inset button 20-pts from layoutMarginsGuide on each side
            applyFiltersBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            applyFiltersBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            // make button height 40-pts
            applyFiltersBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
        ])
        
    }
}

class SectionFooterViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // register cell class for reuse
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        // register Section Footer class for reuse
        tableView.register(MySectionFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "mySectionFooter")

        tableView.sectionFooterHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 50
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier:"mySectionFooter") as! MySectionFooterView
        return view
    }
}
```

To handle tapping the button in the section footer, you can either assign it an action in `viewForFooterInSection`, or build that action into the `MySectionFooterView` class and use a closure or protocol / delegate pattern.

Comment: Got you :) will try that out and I'm sorry next time i will be more clear 

Comment: I tried your code but the thing is the footer is not at the bottom :\

Comment: That's why I asked... do you want it to be a **section** footer or a **table** footer, and you said "section." Do you want it at the bottom of the table view instead?

Comment: I meant I want it to be a table footer I just want the footer of the tableView to be at the bottom with a UIButton.

Comment: *"I just want the footer of the tableView to be at the bottom"* ... at the bottom of what? At the bottom of the last row? At the bottom of the view frame? At the bottom of the last row, unless there are enough rows to push the "footer" to the bottom of the view frame? See this:  https://imgur.com/a/v1A4Il2 for the differences. If you want the "footer" to be at the bottom of the **view frame** even if there are only a couple rows, then you need to either add the footer as a table subview or move it outside of the table view itself.

Comment: I want it to be at the bottom of the view frame which is like this : [link](https://programmingwithswift.com/content/images/2020/02/Feature.png) just to place the UIButton at the bottom of the frame

Comment: OK - you almost certainly want to change to a standard `UIViewController` with a tableView and your view-with-button as subviews. To save yourself a lot of time and effort in the future, you may want to review Stack Overflow's [ask].